# Enabling Textbox in Usercontrol using Button from my form in vb.net

Tags: vb.net-2010

Can anyone help me with this?

I have a form namely "frmMainMenu" and has a panel in it.
This is my Main Menu form.
![this is my main menu.][1]

and i have this UserControl namely "uscPOS".

When i clicked F8, the panel inside the form will be the parent of the usercontrol.
like this.

what i want to happen is when i click the New Invoice button from my form, the textbox in usercontrol will be enabled. i have this code in my form

```
Public Class frmMainMenu
Private Sub rbiPOS_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles rbiPOS.Click
    Try
        Dim bLoad As Boolean = False

        If UIPanel.HasChildren Then
            If Not TypeOf (UIPanel.Controls(0)) Is uscPOS Then
                UIPanel.Controls.Clear()
                bLoad = True
            End If
        Else
            bLoad = True
        End If

        If bLoad Then
            Dim f As New uscPOS
            f.Parent = UIPanel
            f.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
            f.Visible = True
        End If

        rbrPOS.Enabled = True
        rbrProducts.Enabled = True
        rbrDiscount.Enabled = True
        rbrExact.Enabled = True

        btnNewInvoice.Enabled = True
        btnCancel.Enabled = False
        btnSettle.Enabled = False
        btnAddtxt.Enabled = False
        btnDelete.Enabled = False
        btnDiscount.Enabled = False

        rbtSenior.Enabled = False
        rbtExact.Enabled = False

        txtAmountTendered.Enabled = False
        txtDiscount.Enabled = False
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical Or MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "rbiPOS_Click")
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub btnNewInvoice_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnNewInvoice.Click
    Try
        btnNewInvoice.Enabled = False
        btnCancel.Enabled = True
        btnSettle.Enabled = True
        btnAddtxt.Enabled = True
        btnDelete.Enabled = True
        btnDiscount.Enabled = True

        rbtSenior.Enabled = False
        rbtExact.Enabled = False

        txtAmountTendered.Enabled = False
        txtDiscount.Enabled = False

        **'starting from this part
        Dim f As New uscPOS
        f.txtCustomerName.Enabled = True
        f.txtCustomerAddress.Enabled = True
        f.txtContactNo.Enabled = True
        f.txtSearchProductCode.Enabled = True
        'i tried to put message box here just to know if this part is happening but the messagebox is displayed
        MsgBox("I am able to go to this part of code.")
        f.pnecbxSearchProductName.Visible = True
        f.pnecbxSearchProductName.Enabled = True
        f.pnecbxSearchProductName.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom
        f.txtUnitPrice.Enabled = True
        f.txtQuantity.Enabled = True
        MsgBox("I am at the end of the code.")
        'to this part, is not happening.**

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical Or MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "btNNewInvoice_Click")
    End Try
End Sub
End Class
```

but i can't understand why it didn't enable my textbox in my usercontrol, no errors or warning. can anyone enlighten me with this? i can't move on to my project because of this. help will be much appreciated. thanks..

Comment: using event handler, do you think it'll work? thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You create your user control but never add it to your panel.

```
UIPanel.controls.add(f) 'adds your control to the panel
```